# Javascript call class w/o parenthesis (jQuery style)

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I am trying to set up library like jQuery simply for learning purposes. I have it working decently well, and I can do method chaining as needed. The problem I am having is being able to call a method with the class' parenthesis:

What I have to do:

```
$foo().get('id1');
```

What I would like to do:

```
$foo.get('id1');
```

Here is the current javascript:

```
(function( window ) {
    var document = window.document;
    var fooTools = (function() {
        var fooTools = function( selector ) {
            return new fooTools.base.init( selector );
        };

        fooTools.base = fooTools.prototype = {
            init: function( selector ) {
                if( !selector ) {
                    return this;
                } 
                if( selector ) {
                    this[0] = selector;
                        this.length = 1;
                        return this;
                }
            },

            get: function( id ) {
                return document.getElementById( id );
            },

            //..other methods

        };       
        fooTools.base.init.prototype = fooTools.base;
        return fooTools;    
    }());
    window.fooTools = window.$foo = fooTools;
}( window ));
```

Currently it works just fine, but if I do not include the parenthesis I get an error that the .get() method does not exist. I still want to maintain the ability to use parenthesis for other methods, so i just want it be optional. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change:

```
window.fooTools = window.$foo = fooTools;
```

to:

```
window.$foo = new fooTools();
window.fooTools = fooTools;
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eGrRx/)

---

EDIT

```
window.fooTools = fooTools;
window.$foo= fooTools;
window.$foo.get = fooTools.prototype.get;
```

[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eGrRx/3/)

Comment: This takes away my ability to use it with the parenthesis when needed, like `$foo('id1').attr({...})`

Comment: @Headspin See Kevin's answer; that way you can do both.

Comment: Doesnt this mean I will have to specify every method i want to be able to call w/o parenthesis like this?

Comment: It seems jQuery works a little more elegantly. Do you know how? I am looking at the uncompressed version and cannot wrap my head around it. They are doing something like `jQuery.extend = jQuery.fn.extend = function() {}`  but I have had no luck

Comment: jQUery.fn is actually just jQuery.prototype, so in essence it's very similar to this approach

Comment: So in essence, I could create a method which dynamically sets all my 'non parenthesis' methods in this fashion, and call it in my init constructor? Anyways, I got it working and I thank you for leading me to the answers

Answer (score 2):

Define two different kind of methods, just like we do in jQuery.

If the method needs parenthesis such as `$foo('id1').attr({...})` define it using `$foo.prototype.method = function`, else, define it as a property of `$foo` `$foo.get = function(){...}`

Edit: This is actually based on IAbstract's answer.

It would be `fooTools.prototype` not `$foo.prototype` since `fooTools` is the class that `$foo` is an instance of.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to define `$foo` as something other than a function--right now you're returning `fooTools`, which is a function, so you need to call it in order to access what it exposes.

(Drat, he beat me to it.)